# Multiline Template - string escaping in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to get an effect similar to this article: https://gryzli.info/2017/12/21/ansible-debug-print-variables/

Which means in my case:

```
- name: Gather facts
  vars:
    msg: |
    "{{ansible_distribution}}"
    "{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}"
    "{{ansible_distribution_release}}"
    "{{ansible_distribution_version}}"
```

The problem ist that without quotes it throws an error to add the quotes. With quotes it throws the same error:

```
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when theystart a value....
```

How do I correctly escape this multiline string so that Ansible can parse it? Or does this kind of code no longer work?

Comment: "{{ansible_distribution,ansible_distribution_major_version,ansible_distribution_release,ansible_distribution_version)}}" - works but it's not multiline.

Comment: Btw using the fix below escaping with "" is no longer necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"How do I correctly escape this multiline string so that Ansible can parse it?"*

A: The problem is the indentation of the block. Quoting from [Example 8.3. Invalid Block Scalar Indentation Indicators](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979)

> ERROR:
>
> - A leading all-space line must not have too many spaces.
> - A following text line must not be less indented.
> - **The text is less indented than the indicated level.**

The correct syntax is (with or without quotation)

```
  vars:
    msg: |
      "{{ansible_distribution}}"
      "{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}"
      "{{ansible_distribution_release}}"
      "{{ansible_distribution_version}}"
```